# Is it possible to merge cells of a datagrid vertically in clarity framework

Tags: css, angular, vmware-clarity

I want to create a datagrid that has cells that are vertically next to each other and has the same name merged. Tried to google many sources but couldn't find any help.

Comment: I'm not very clear what you mean, can you give more detail please?

Comment: @Jerermy Wilken
like merge multiple cells in 1 collumn into 1 cell like in excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with Clarity in a datagrid, as this breaks the pattern of rows holding content atomically. Pagination, rendering, sorting, filtering would all be much more complex to implement and understand for the user.

I would suggest that you use a regular table which can have column or row spans attached to a cell, or just have each row repeat the content in the cell instead of trying to merge it.